# Correct finishing of server's thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have windows form. In the constructor server thread starts

```
thServer = new Thread(ServerThread);
thServer.Start();
```

In the server thread there is TCP listener loop:

```
 while (true) {
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    ...
    }
```

When I close main form, this thread continues to wait TCPClient's requests. How can I stop this routine? 
Thank you.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to add " (C#)" to your title. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread theServer = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler( Form1_FormClosed );

        theServer = new Thread( ServerThread );
        theServer.IsBackground = true;
        theServer.Start();

    }

    void ServerThread()
    {
        //TODO
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed( object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e )
    {
        theServer.Interrupt();
        theServer.Join( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 2 ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it is right code. But when I close my application func Form1_FormClosed() is not called.. (I checked while debugging)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to mark the thread as a background thread - then it won't keep your process running when your main form closes:

```
thServer = new Thread(ServerThread);
thServer.IsBackground = true;
thServer.Start();
```

[MSDN: Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add a flag which acts as the condition of the while loop.
Of course you could also set the IsBackground property of your Thread object, but you might want to execute some clean-up code.

Example:

```
class Server : IDisposable
{
    private bool running = false;
    private Thread thServer;

    public Server()
    {
        thServer = new Thread(ServerThread);
        thServer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        running = false;
        // other clean-up code
    }

    private ServerThread()
    {
        running = true;
        while (running)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (Server server = new Server())
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the solution to this exact same problem.](http://www.groupsrv.com/dotnet/about76603.html) (take a look at the SimpleServer class)

The idea is to stop the `TcpClient`, so the call to `AcceptTcpClient` aborts. After the call to `AcceptTcpClient` you might need to ask if the socket is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Make the special boolean variable indicating that form is about to close. Check its value in the background thread and break the loop when it is true. In main form set the variable value to true and call thServer.Join() to await the thread to finish. Then you can safely close the 
form. Something like this:

In form closing handler:

```
abortThread = true;
thServer.Join();
```

In server thread loop:

```
while (true)
{
   if (abortThread)
      break;

   TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
   ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem if `AcceptTcpClient` has already been called.

Comment: I tried it. If there are no clients, server thread will be in the waiting mode